# How to use dojo deferred to finish the query, and then call other function with it result?

Tags: javascript, dojo, deferred

I have several query tasks, some of which may also include query task. How to use dojo deferred to make sure query is finished and then run other code?

Here is the JavaScript pseudo code:

```
// About queryTask: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html

var data=[];

settings for query1...;
queryTask1.execute(query1);
queryTask1.on("complete", function (evt1) 
{
    var fset1 = evt1.featureSet;
    var resultFeatures1 = fset1.features;
    ...

    settings for query2...;
    queryTask2.execute(query2);
    queryTask2.on("complete", function (evt2) 
    {
        var fset2 = evt2.featureSet;
        var resultFeatures2 = fset2.features;
        ...    

    });

});

settings for query3...;
queryTask3.execute(query3);
queryTask3.on("complete", function (evt3) 
{
    var fset3 = evt3.featureSet;
    var resultFeatures3 = fset3.features;
    ...

});

ResultToKendoGrid(data); //data is updated in the query task 1 2 and 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your query tasks in `dojo/Deferred` objects, and resolve theme when your tasks complete/reject.

If you need to run some code, when all of your query tasks are completed, therefore all your dojo deferred objects are resolved, your can use `dojo/promise/all` which execute only when all deferred are completed.

Docs:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Deferred.html

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/all.html

```
require(['dojo/Deferred', 'dojo/promise/all'], function(Deferred, all) {
      // code to initate query tasks here
      var deferredTask1 = new Deferred();
      queryTask1.execute(query1);
      queryTask1.on("complete", function(evt1) {
        deferredTask1.resolve(evt1);
      });
      var deferredTask2 = new Deferred();
      queryTask2.execute(query1);
      queryTask2.on("complete", function(evt1) {
        deferredTask2.resolve(evt1);
      });
      all([deferredTask1, deferredTask1]).then(function(results) {
        // results will be an Array
      });

      // -- or --
      all({
        deferredTask1: deferredTask1,
        deferredTask2: deferredTask2
      }).then(function(results) {
        // results will be an Object using the keys "promise1" and "promise2"
      });
    });
```